# Microsoft Graph API - Send Email - NoPermissionsInAccessToken

Tags: ruby, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a Ruby App to send email using Microsoft Graph API.
I get access token without a user based on : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#5-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph

```
url = URI.parse("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == "https")

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri)
req.set_form_data({
    'client_id' => CLIENT_ID, 
    'client_secret' => CLIENT_SCERET,
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
})
response = http.request(req)
```

I got token.

Next, I want send mail to any user with my application on portal azure, which have api permissions for it.

[image]

Then, I call send_mail function.

```
url = URI.parse("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{MYID}/sendMail")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == "https")
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri)
req["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{get_token_without_user}"
req["Content-type"] = "application/json"

req.set_form_data({
    "message": {
       "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
       "body": {
          "contentType": "Text",
          "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
        }
     },
     "toRecipients": [
        {
          "emailAddress": {
             "address": "to_email@gmail.com"
          }
     }],
     "saveToSentItems": "false"
})
response = http.request(req)
```

I receive this error :

[image]

So, can anybody guide me where is my mistake ? Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you have to check Microsoft's API for this.

Comment: @VatsalJain I updated more source to get token. Is it ok ?

Comment: v2.0 is missing in the url and try adding the header for Content-Type

Comment: Sorry, it still does not working. :(

Comment: It would help to see the source code that makes the actual call to the graph endpoint. Perhaps there is something wrong with the request and not the token...

Comment: @RyanTran - is this resolved? could you post the answer to this pls?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby -- is the scope parameter URLEncoded when sent over the wire?

Grab the response and have a look. Does it have an access_token property? If so, copy the value of that property and paste it in https://jwt.ms.  Look for the scopes or roles in the decoded token - it should match what has been setup in the AAD portal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
First, when I send request to get token, i got it. Response is not error and contains access_token. => Getting token is ok ?
Second, i also paste this token in https://jwt.ms. It returns many properties but it does not contain any role. => I think i missed it in AAD. But, i set all permissions about Mail for this application like picture.

Comment: I also update source code that makes the actual call to the graph endpoint. Can you help me review it ?

Comment: Hi @RyanTran, I am also having the same issue. Did you try to fix this issue? Please let me know your workaround for this. Thanks.